# Pull a document in one collection using a property from a document in another collection (Mongo, MEAN Stack)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack

**Context:**

I am working on a test-taking web-app, where users answer questions in an examination format.

I currently have two collections:

- *tests*
- *questions*

Each document in the *tests* collection has a `questions` array that contains the Mongo IDs of documents in the *questions* collections.

**My Question...**

Is it possible to (all at once / in one go): Retrieve a specific document in *tests* using a provided Mongo ID and then use the Mongo IDs saved in the `questions` array (within that document) to then pull documents from *questions*?

My closest guess is to use Mongoose's DBRef convention, but I can't quite understand how to use it in this context (and even if I did, I don't understand how I can retrieve multiple questions and save them under a single test).

I would appreciate any and all help with this!

**P.S.** The reason *questions* and *tests* are separate is so that we can randomize the order of questions when the user takes the exam in the web-app.

Comment: _populate_ is what you need. Check docs mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

Answer (score 1):

Go the other direction. Put the testId on the `Question` model:

```
var TestSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   name: String
});
var Test = mongoose.model("Test", TestSchema);

var QuestionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    testId: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: "Test"
    },
    text: String,
    answer: String
});
QuestionSchema.index({testId: 1})
var Question = mongoose.model("Question", QuestionSchema);
```

You have three situations; you have a `question` document in memory and you want to find the `test` it belongs to:

```
Test.findOne({_id: question.testId},callback);
```

Or you have a `question` document in memory and want to find all `questions` that belong to the same test:

```
Question.find({testId: question.testId}, callback);
```

Or, you have a `test` document in memory and want to find all of it's `questions`:

```
Question.find({testId: test._id}, callback);
```

I see `populate()` pop up as an answer on any question resembling yours. I want to make sure people realize `populate()` isn't a SQL `JOIN`. From the docs:

> Populated paths are no longer set to their original _id , their value is replaced with the mongoose document returned from the database by performing a separate query before returning the results.

`populate()` is just syntactic sugar for serializing a second `find()`.